# How do I configure Beyond Compare (BC4) to "Open with... Parent Folder" in Windows Explorer for a selected file in Windows 10?

Tags: explorer, beyondcompare4

How to Configure BC4 to "Open with... Parent Folder" in Windows Explorer for the selected file(s) in Windows 10

I use Beyond Compare (v4) many times per day, because it offers features that Windows Explorer or Finder do not for sizing folder contents, synchronizing file systems, etc.  I frequently need to open the containing (parent) FOLDER for the selected file(s) displayed in BC4 Folder Compare.

Presently, I navigate to the folder containing the file for which I want to open parent folder, but then I must navigate upward and right click and say "Open with ..." and select "Associated Application".  These are extra time consuming steps, because I may do this several times per day.

I want to configure an "Open with..." option to open the file's parent folder (in Windows Explorer), NOT the viewer or editor for the selected file(s).

I tried various options, but cannot get it to work.  If I set the "Command Line" parameter to Windows Explorer executable (Explorer.exe) by itself, it does not work.

I tried the %P (relative path) and %p (absolute path) with the the  or  selected, but it did not work.

QUESTION: How do I configure this mouse right-click option to open the file(s) parent folder, and also assign a keyboard shortcut in Beyond Compare 4?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: Through trial and error I figured out what the exact syntax and parameter settings are for the fields "Command Line", "Working Folder" and "Accepts Files" and "Accepts Folders" options.

```
> Description: Folder in Windows File Explorer 
> Shortcut:  Alt-F Command
> line: C:\Windows\explorer.exe %P   <<< enter this without quotes >>>
> Working folder: BLANK Accepts file: CHECKED Accepts folders: CHECKED
> Multiple instances: CHECKED    <<< opens only one Explorer, multiple files can be selected.
```

The relative path (%P) argument is needed alone (WITHOUT THE FILENAME OR FILE EXTENSION) on the command line to get this to work.